# Applescript create folder with properties

Tags: applescript

This is my code:

```
on startButton_(sender)
    set folderDestination to choose folder
    log folderDestination
    log nameOfFolder
    tell application "Finder"
    make new folder at folderDestination with properties {name:nameOfFolder}
    end tell
end startButton_
```

The idea ist to make a folder at the folder Destination (folderDestination) with the name of the folder (nameOfFolder).
This is the error from the console

```
2021-03-13 09:28:02.844240+0100 Folder Creator[1571:39314] *** -[AppDelegate startButton:]: Finder got an error: Can’t make «class ocid» id «data optr0000000059FEE7F626C77C59» into type Unicode text. (error -1700)
```

But the log from the folder Destination and name did work:

```
2021-03-13 09:28:02.750713+0100 Media Folder Creator[1571:39314] file:///Users/name/Desktop/
```

and:

```
2021-03-13 09:28:02.753207+0100 Media Folder Creator[1571:39314] folderName123
```

The textfield in Xcode is connected to nameOfFolder.
Model Key Path: nameOfFolder

I do not know where the error is.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `nameOfFolder` is an `NSString` object, you have to bridge it to AppleScript by coercing it to `text`:

```
make new folder at folderDestination with properties {name:nameOfFolder as text}
```

But since you are already in the Cocoa world it would be more efficient to create the folder with `NSFileManager`.

```
on startButton:sender
    set folderDestination to POSIX path of (choose folder)
    log folderDestination
    log nameOfFolder
    set fileManager to current application's NSFileManager's defaultManager()
    set {success, fmError} to fileManager's createDirectoryAtPath:(folderDestination & nameOfFolder as text) withIntermediateDirectories:false attributes:(missing value) |error|:(reference)
    if success is false then log fmError's localizedDescription()
end startButton:
```

Comment: OK. Thanks. Cool. Yeah, I think it's a good idea to use NSFileManager.